# How to write a hex value as it is to a file?

Tags: python

I need to create a file which contains only hex data.

Suppose I have an integer value 10, I want hexadecimal 'a' the value written to the file. The file should have only 1 byte size.

I tried the format, `binascci.hexlify` etc but it is not giving the correct solution. If I directly use hex(10), it will add 0x to the file.

If I write 25, the file will contain two characters 1 and 9 (25(dec) = 19(hex))

Kindly let me know the correct mechanism.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want the contents of the file to be `b'a'` or `b'\x0a'` or something else?

Comment: I am not familiar with the " b' " term. What I want is simple. say value = 25. I want to write value to a file. Since 25 needs only one byte, when I write it to the file it should be 1 byte long only. The file size will ultimately be 1 byte

Comment: Okay, let's take this step by step. Is the file supposed to be a text file, containing the letter "a"? Or is it supposed to be a binary file, containing a byte with the value 10?

Comment: It must be a binary file containing a byte with the value 10

Comment: So then this answers your question, right? [How can I write 1 byte to a binary file in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/39364905)

Comment: I just saw the chr method. chr(value) is converting it into 1 byte. That is working for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

See the [hex() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#hex):

```
>>> '%#x' % 15, '%x' % 15, '%X' % 15
('0xf', 'f', 'F')
>>> format(15, '#x'), format(15, 'x'), format(15, 'X')
('0xf', 'f', 'F')
>>> f'{15:#x}', f'{15:x}', f'{15:X}'
('0xf', 'f', 'F')
```

Comment: They are now a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

```
format(10,'x')
format(25,'x')
```

---

**output**

```
'a'
'19'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"{:x}".format(i)
```

If you want to make a function out of this:

```
enhex = "{:x}".format
```